# jstl c:set unexpected parse

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, jstl

I'm trying to set one array of the Strings *"GetD"* and *"GetG"* to the variable *controllers* using *jstl c:set*

I put them in the body like this

```
<c:set var="controllers" scope="request" >GetD, GetG</c:set>
```

They show up like this in the build and get sent as a single String to the receiving servlet (*GetD, GetG*).

```
<input name="controllers" value="GetD, GetG" type="hidden">
```

If i put them in like this

```
<c:set var="controllers" scope="request" >"GetD", "GetG"</c:set>
```

I instead get the ugliest outcome

```
<input name="controllers" value="" getd",="" "getg""="" type="hidden">
```

I guess I don't need to explain why that would be a problem in the servlet...

So as I only have two of them here I put them in as two rows

```
<c:set var="controllers" scope="request" value="GetD"/>
<c:set var="controllers" scope="request" value="GetG"/>
```

Then only the latest one get sent (recieving *[GetG]*). I guess the first one is written over even though I thougt it would just append.

*I have tried some even more stupid ways like *"'GetD', 'GetG'"* and *GetD ", " GetG* as well but no success.

I build and debug it in Eclipse on a Tomcat 8.5 service.

Right now I have solved it by sending it as a single String and split on "*,*". It is butt ugly and I want the proper solution. Can anyone see the problem?

Comment: *"I'm trying to set one array [...] using jstl `<c:set>`"* Well, that's a problem, because `<c:set>` with text content doesn't create an array. It assigns the text content to the variable as a string. The Java equivalent of your first two `<c:set>` examples are: `String controllers = "GetD, GetG";` and `String controllers = "\"GetD\", \"GetG\"";`. The Java equivalent of the last two is: `String controllers = "GetD";  controllers = "GetG";`, where the second assignment overrides the first one. That's how `<c:set>` works. Read the doc.

Comment: That is a duplicate. I did look at that specific question but I missed the fact that the statement `and in the second it is an array {"One", "Two", "Three"}` is just wrong.

Comment: You're right, your question is a duplicate. That's why I closed it as such.